# Does Flow have a library of interfaces similar to DefinitellyTyped in Typescript?

Tags: flowtype

I am starting with Flow, switching from Typescript.
TS contains a large library of interfaces in DefnitellyTyped.

Does flow have a similar kind of library of interfaces? Am searching for a library for 
React and ReactDOM, Underscore and more.

Answer (score 4):

It does, now: https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed

> `flow-typed` is a
>   [repository](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/tree/master/definitions)
>   of third-party  [library interface
>   definitions](http://flowtype.org/docs/third-party.html)  for use with
>   [Flow](http://flowtype.org/).
>
> You can grab definitions directly from this GitHub repo, or you can
>   use the CLI (currently in beta) to install a libdef for a given
>   library:
>
> ```
> $ npm install -g flow-typed
> $ cd /path/to/my/project
> $ flow-typed install -f 0.30 rxjs@5.0.0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Flow contains library definitions already bundled. You can have a look in this folder: https://github.com/facebook/flow/tree/master/lib
It includes interfaces for React and ReactDOM but I believe Underscore is missing.
It's also pretty easy to extend them if necessary.

Their documentation is also a good place to start and they cover the topic of checking third-party code using interfaces. It might help get you started: http://flowtype.org/docs/third-party.html